# How to find user specific branches in remote repository?

Tags: git

Our remote repository is a big garbage heap of stale branches and I am trying to clean that up. I can find all branches in repository by following command. This gives me all merged branches for all users.

**Git command:**

```
$ for branch in `git branch -r --merged | grep -v HEAD`; do echo -e `git show --format="%ci %cr %an" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
```

**Output:**

```
2018-08-10 17:04:24 +0530 3 days ago User1  origin/Branch-1
2018-08-10 14:32:56 -0400 3 days ago User2  origin/Branch-2
2018-08-09 16:44:44 -0400 4 days ago User3  origin/Branch-3
```

How can I search branch(es) for specific user? i.e. all branch(es) for `User1` in above example.

Comment: Simply pipe that through `grep User1`?

Comment: Pipe it to something which can do the searching such as [less](https://www.lifewire.com/what-to-know-less-command-4051972) or [grep](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/).